# I have a problem using cnosdb's tenant feature. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: cnosdb

I created a tenant and a user, and gave the user the owner rights of the tenant. Here is my SQL statement:

```
CREATE TENANT tenant_a;
CREATE USER user_a;
ALTER TENANT tenant_a ADD USER user_a AS owner;
```

Then I query this table and find that there is already a tenant that I created:
[image]
Then I try to delete this tenant, this is an error occurred, this is the SQL statement:

```
DROP TENANT tenant_a;
```

An error occurred after executing the delete statement：

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030028","error_message":"Decode message error reason: invalid type: null, expected a boolean at line 1 column 10"}
```

At this point, I checked again and found that the tenant was no longer available：
[image]
Although I finally achieved the purpose of deleting the tenant, there was an error in the process. I want to know what this error message means.

Comment: What is the version of cnosdb you use, I did not reproduce this problem in the v2.3 version.

Comment: I encountered this in version v2.3.1